# BASH one-line alphabetical mass file sort using for, mv, and grep

Tags: bash, sorting, for-loop, grep, mv

## Problem

I've got thousands of files with the format `"^[[:digit:]]\{4\} - [[:alpha:]].*"`, for exampe: 7958 - a3ykof zyimeo3.txt. I'm trying to simply move them into folders alphabetically beginning with the first alpha-character after the hyphen.

I feel like I'm so close to getting this to happen the way I want but there's a (hopefully simple) problem.

I tested the commmand with echo first to make sure it grabs the correct information. Then I tried to execute it for real with mv. I've included some examples below based on this list of files:

```
1439 - a74389 josifj3oj.txt
3589 - Bfoei 839982 3il.txt
4719 - an38n8f n839mm20 mi02.txt
6398 - b39ji oij3o8 j2o.txt
9287 - A2984 j289jj9 oiw.txt
.... several thousand more files
```

## Examples

### This works

This lists all the files starting with the letter "a" (after the 4 digits-space-hyphen-space pattern in the beginning):

```
for i in "$(ls | grep -i "^[[:digit:]]\{4\} - a")"; do echo "$i"; done
```

### This fails

This doesn't put all the files starting with the letter "a" (after the 4 digits-space-hyphen-space pattern) in the "A" folder:

```
for i in "$(ls | grep -i "^[[:digit:]]\{4\} - a")"; do mv "$i" A; done
```

I expected this second command to move each file named "#### - a*" or "#### - A*" to the folder named A. But it sees it as one big string/filename joined by "\n".

Here's an example error message:

```
mv: cannot stat '1439 - a74389 josifj3oj.txt\n9287 - A2984 j289jj9 oiw.txt\n2719 - an38n8f n839mm20 mi02.txt': No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

## Edit

Between @alvits's answer and @chepner's and @courtlandj comments, what worked flawless for me was this:

```
for directory in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir -p "$directory" &&
    find . -iregex "./[0-9]* - ${directory}.*" -exec mv -t "$directory" {} +; 
done
```

Comment: The quote in `"$(....)"` makes it a single long string. Parsing the output of `ls` isn't your best choice here cause the filenames contain spaces. You can use `find` and use `-print0` to separate the file lists with `\0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do it.

```
for directory in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir "$directory" &&
    find . -iregex "./[0-9]* - ${directory}.*" -exec mv "{}" "$directory" \;
done
```

The `for` loop will query for filenames according to each directory they belong.

The `find` command will find the files and move them to the directory.

Comment: You don't need an extra shell invocation; `-exec mv {} "$directory" \;` will work just fine.

Comment: Having said that, you might want to use `-exec bash -c 'mv "$@" "$1"' _ "$directory" {} +` to batch multiple files into a single call to `mv`. :) With GNU `mv`, you can simplify that back to `-exec mv -t "$directory" {} +`.

Comment: (*grumble* about the lack of quoting -- if you somehow had a character inside the `{A..Z}` range in `IFS`, that would expand to nothing, unless changed from `$directory` to "$directory"` everywhere appropriate).

Comment: @chepner - I'll add it and mention that it will not work with `find` version 4.4 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

BASH has RE-like globbing, and sequence creation, built-in. You can make use of it something like this:

```
for i in {{A..Z},{a..z}}; do
  mkdir "${i}" && mv [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" - ${i}"*" "${i}"
done
```

You notice the four repetitions of the digits, and yeah it looks clumsier than a normal RE like `[0-9]{4}`.

Comment: If the `mkdir` fails for some reason, you don't want to try to move a bunch of files to a non-existent directory.

Comment: If it fails because that directory already exists, then you might be okay to proceed. `mkdir -p`?

Comment: Yes; I noticed that was missing, then forgot to add it myself.